# Transferred Files won't open

Tags: icons

Forgive newbie question. I've had Ubuntu/Linux installed on an HP LT that used to run Windows 11 (yeah, I know). Old files like documents and photo's were saved by taking the disk out before wiping then putting it back in once Ubuntu installed.
I can see the icons on the desktop but clicking on them seems to have no effect - the disk doesn't make the usual chuntering sounds.
I did right-click but no idea what to choose on the drop-down menu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please provide more info like your Ubuntu version? That would be helpful for other people who try to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the screen is a purple octopus. I'll see if I can find out.